# debian 6 language change system error

Tags: debian, localization, language

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = "ru_UA.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

**What do I do with this? I get it in almost every package I install.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the following command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Select the locale(s) you want to have on your system (based on your post, you probably want ru_UA.UTF8 to be selected). On the next screen, give the default locale you wish to use.

Comment: I did that.  I actually want en_US but the sys admins installed ru_UA.  Anyway.  I deselected everything but en_US and made the default en_US. through the command you stated.  BUT after I reboot the system the same old problem is back again.  How do I get it working after a system reboot?

Comment: And I also get this everytime I log into the terminal `-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (ru_UA.UTF-8): No such file or directory
`

Comment: You don't have some locale settings in you rc files (.bash_profile, .bashrc, or similar), do you? The system default locale settings can be overridden by exporting the LC_* variables, most notably LC_ALL, which, if set, acts as a "user default" locale setting. Check the output of the `locale` command. Usually, if LC_ALL is empty, but all the others (except for LANG and LANGUAGE, both of which can be empty) are set, then the system default settings are in place. If LC_ALL is set, then the locale settings got overridden.